# Which place is good for vipassana meditation?

Tags: vipassana, meditation, meditation-recommendation

Please recommend good place for Vipassana meditation for in 2017.

Including

- Availability of visa
- it does not matter short 7-14 days or long (in months) Vipassana meditation course
- If it is remote place better
- It is not book fly and go vacation so manual work or queuing is ok
- If it is a place that we need to ordain to be a monk before starting Vipassana meditation, I prefer.

Answer (score 3):

These are two prominent places in Sri Lanka. Sri Lanka offers 1 year residence visa easily if you have a recommendation beforehand. Normally in Sri Lanka, temperory ordination is discouraged and permanent ordination is possible at anytime.

1. **Mitirigala Nissarana Vanaya**

   - Teacher- Ven. Udairiyagama Dhammajiva Maha Thero (U Dhammajiva
     Sayadaw), Excellent knowledge in Dhamma, Pali, Burmese and English, Specialty in Mindfulness and emphasizes the value of mindfulness
   - Meditation Technique - Satipatthana meditation, Burmese Mahasi/Panditarama Technique (Vipassana) and [Sri
     Lankan Nanarama Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissarana_Vanaya_Meditation_System) (Vipassana with Samatha)
   - Retreats - 3 days, 7 days, 10 days, 20 days and extensive periods are
     allowed for serious practitioners and for the meditators who are
     expecting the ordaination
   - Location - Mitirigala,Kirindivela, Sri Lanka
   - More Information - nissarana.lk (Official Website)
2. **Sanghopasthana Suva Sevana**

   - Teacher- Ven. Katukurunde Nyanananda Maha Thero (Bhikkhu Nanananda)
     [A famous book author and a meditation master], Excellent knowledge in Dhamma, Pali and English, Advises not to be in a hurry but to practice Samatha also for aiding Vipassana, Slowly-Mindfully-Carefully. Appreciates dedication for practicing.
   - Meditation Technique - Both Samatha and Vipassana, Metta Meditation
     and probably Sri Lankan Nanarama Method (Vipassana with Samatha)
   - Retreats - Any time is possible with prior notice. No allocated dates. special consideration for dedicated meditators and  dedicated practitioners who are expecting the ordaination.
   - Location - Kirillawala Watta, Dammulla, Karandana, Sri Lanka
   - More Information - http://www.seeingthroughthenet.net (Official
     Website)

Additionally there are more meditation centers which are famous in different aspects. NaUyana Aranya in Melsiripura (Burmese Pa-auk system), Kanduboda M.C. (Burmese Mahasi System), Goenka centers in Kandy, Anuradhapura and Kosgama (Burmese Sayagi U Ba Kin system)

Comment: I can agree with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following have a wide outreach:

- http://www.dhamma.org/en/index
- http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html

So there might be a place near to where you live.

Also you can try: [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/)

Answer (score 2):

Pa-Auk Forest Monastery, in Myanmar (Burma).

http://paaukforestmonastery.org/index.htm

However, you will have to develop access concentration before you can begin Vipassana (Satipatthana).

You may remain there for a period of months or years, even lifetime if you are able to renew your visa each year. You also have the chance to ordain after a few weeks or months, once deemed trustworthy.

At first you will be able to get a visa of 3 months and extend the visa for a 1 year period each time. Yearly visa is about 100$ US.

May you realize Nibbana and know true peace and freedom, friend.

Comment: Pa-auk teachers are tipitaka memorizers. It is the best advance meditation school because the teachers will taught the practitioners follow tipitaka&commentary in every step. We also can taught vipassanā first, but not recommend, The reason of samatha first is inside this link.

http://www.paauktawyathailand.org/main/index.php/en/about . 

The reason from sutta:

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22512/10100

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the south-central United States, there is the The Southwest Vipassana Meditation Center in Kaufman, Texas. It is about an hour and fifteen minutes drive southeast from the Dallas-Fort Worth Airport. https://www.siri.dhamma.org/

Answer (score 1):

Blue Mountains Insight Meditation centre - Medlow Bath Australia. 1hr45min drive from Sydney Airport. Train station is walking distance to centre. 
Individual rooms with share bathroom. Separate accommodation for men and women. Books out fast as they only have accommodation for about 20 people.